# Spring Boot Application has been compiled by more recent version of Java runtime

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to launch my jar file for my spring boot application but I keep getting the error that it has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0. I feel like I have tried everything I believe I am using the latest versions of Java. Is there anything I can do? If there is anything to download could you please link it?

Comment: `java -version` in command line pls?

Comment: Just to add class version 52 = java 8, which is not the latest version.  Suspect you may not be running the version of java you think.  Also, how are you running the jar?  Command line?  OS would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I solved the issue by removing the javapath path variable and restarting.

I believe it was the following I removed:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath